# Зачем появляются отступы по умолчанию?

Tags: html, css, html5

Пишу просто так менюшку.
Вот html:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

И у навигационного меню появляется отступ. Я же указал `margin :0`.
Что за отступы это по умолчанию и как их убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это отступ не тега ul, а тега body

в начале стилей задайте

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: а как ещё можно к этим текстам прикрутить иконки ?слева или справа

Comment: @elik если вам нужно задать вопрос - задайте его отдельно. См. [help]

Comment: если стандартным способом, то через атрибут "list-style-image", но многие пользуются псевдоклассами :after и :befor (они служат для добавления доп. контента в начале и конце блока)